# Étale extension of local fields

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be a finite extension of a local field $K$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be the unique prime in $\mathcal{O}_K$. Say $\mathfrak{p}$ factors as $\mathfrak{p} \mathcal{O}_L = \mathfrak{q}_1^{e_1} \cdots \mathfrak{q}_n^{e_n}$. When is $\mathcal{O}_{L} / \mathcal{O}_K$ étale in terms of the ramification indices and inertial degrees of $\mathfrak{p}$?

Comment: Hm. Certainly, one should have $e_{1} = \ldots = e_{n} = 1$ (or else, if $e_{i} > 1$, then $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_\mathfrak{q_{i}} = \mathfrak{q_{i}}^{e_{i}}\mathcal{O}_\mathfrak{q_{i}}$). If this is the case, is it guaranteed that the corresponding extension of residue fields is separable? Not sure. Flatness comes for free: the inclusion $\mathcal{O}_{K} \to \mathcal{O}_{L}$ is manifestly injective, which is enough by the local criterion for flatness.

Comment: If your definition of local field requires that the residue field of $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ at $\mathfrak{p}$ be finite, then I suppose this is immediate.

Comment: @AlexWertheim I don't know why people use the term local field. It is supposed to mean finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ or $\Bbb{F}_p((t))$, it seems a theorem says those are the only complete DVR with finite residue field

Comment: @DeanYoung : Your questions don't make sense because once you know the definition of etale then the answer is obvious, by definition. For a finite extension of a complete DVR there is only one prime above the base prime. For non-complete DVR there are several primes, try with $\Bbb{Z}_{(5)}[x]/(x^2+1)$. Local ring means a ring with only one maximal ideal. Discretely valued field means a DVR together with its fraction field. In other words define your field and $O_K$ and etale